# Loading JSON data via DataPortal into Parameter

Tags: pyomo

I want to load Data from a JSON file into my Pyomo Model.
I start with

```
m = AbstractModel()
m.T = RangeSet(1,48,1)
m.TS = Param(m.T)
dp = DataPortal()
```

Later I want to load my json file to populate my parameter TS
with

```
dp.load(param = m.TS, filename = data.json)
```

The data is a timeseries indexed by integers 1,2,...,48
Thus 
it looks like this:

```
{ 
  "1" : 0.0001,
  "2" : 0.1 ,
  ....,
  "48" : 0
}
```

then i create

```
create_instance(dp)
```

I get the folowing error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to set value for param=TS, index=1, value=35.676187.
        source error message="Index '1' is not valid for indexed component 'TS'"
```

Comment: When testing with a `ConcreteModel` instead of an `AbstractModel`, `1 in m.T` returns True, while it doesn't if I use `AbstractModel`. I guess you have to create the instance before using the data portal, since `m.T.display()` shows that the RangeSet is not constructed.

Comment: Oh, also, forgive me for not being proefficient with a DataPortal, so I can be wrong. But I see that your data looks a lot like a dictionary. If you look at your keys, you can see that they are strings and not numbers. Since `RangeSet()` generates a set with numbers, maybe it doesn't find the`"1"` string into your set of numbers, and that would also explain your error.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your ideas. But since I need to iterate over index i think numeric data is necessary since order is changed when I use strings.

Comment: I understand. I meant that maybe your keys are not converted into numbers between your JSON and Pyomo and that could be a problem. But I am more willing to bet it is a problem with the way you handle the `AbstractModel`.

Comment: @V.Brunelle is right, the fact that those keys are strings is definitely an issue. You can either convert those keys to integer, or use YAML right away, since it supports integers as keys.

Answer (score 0):

So I came with a solution to this problem.
The JSON file should be written in this fashion:

```
{"TS":
    [
     {'index':1, 'value':1},
     {'index':2, 'value':0},
     {'index':3, 'value':1},
    ]
}
```